# GroupBox not in toolbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I cant find groupbox in toolbox. It is showing in the list of components and it is checked. I also tried to insert it through code but it is also not showing in the code. In some pre made pages like login and createuser wizard visual studio is showing the groupbox. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: I am making a web application and cant find System.Windows.Forms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The same functionality you can achieve by the following code:

```
<fieldset class="login">
                <legend>Title</legend>

<div>Content</div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use Panel. Specify the text on GroupingText property.